# How to add Site columns, Content Type and List Definition In Provider Hosted App in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, provider-hosted-app

I've created my Provider Hosted App in SharePoint App. Now I want to add site columns, Content types and List Definition in Host Web.

When I create site columns and add in feature then run app it gives me error.

Can anyone give me example how to create SharePoint Components in HostWeb in Provider Hosted App.

Any article or links are appreciated..!!

Comment: To provision artifacts like site columns, content types etc. in host web using provider hosted add-in (previously app), you need to use CSOM/REST approach. Office PnP has few demo on this.

Comment: I haven't find any example which can help me to create artifacts.. Please help me or provide me some more stuff.

Comment: Do a Google search for "sharepoint remote provisioning"